# Send microphone voice input from Hololens to a PC

Tags: sockets, uwp, voice, hololens

I'd like to send the microphone input voice from Hololens to a PC(Linux or Windows). 
It looks like I need to record my voice with `Windows.Media.Capture` of `UWP`, 
and then I need to send it to a PC with `Windows.Networking.Sockets` of `UWP`.
But I'm not sure how to send audio files with `Windows.Networking.Sockets`. 
Any advice or reference would be of great help.

Comment: Can you include some examples of what you've tried so far, perhaps with some sections of source-code?

Comment: Are you using Unity to develop your application?

Comment: @rwp/ Thank you for your reply. Actually I could not post the code because I could not get started yet. If I succeed, I'll share the code.

Answer (score 0):

**MixedRealityToolkit-Unity**

If you're not already using it, I would highly recommend that you develop your project with Unity. The [MixedRealityToolKit-Unity](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity) has excellent resources for [configuring sharing,](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Sharing/README.md) -- including sending and receiving audio -- and works for most platforms, including HoloLens, UWP, and Linux. The available scripts make it easy to implement complex back-end features into your application.

The following is from the [VoiceChat section](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Sharing/README.md#voicechat)).

> **MicrophoneReceiver.cs**
>
> Receives and plays voice data transmitted through the session server.
>   This data comes from other clients running the MicrophoneTransmitter
>   behaviour.  ([script](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Sharing/Scripts/VoiceChat/MicrophoneReceiver.cs))
>
> **MicrophoneTransmitter.cs**
>
> Transmits data from your microphone to other clients connected to a
>   SessionServer. Requires any receiving client to be running the
>   MicrophoneReceiver script. ([script](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Sharing/Scripts/VoiceChat/MicrophoneTransmitter.cs))

**Developing without Unity**
Even if you are not using Unity, you can still review all of their scripts to find the most efficient way to accomplish sharing.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Unity, but I didn't know how to do with Unity's API, so I tried to use UWP's. I'll do it with the examples that you posted. If I have trouble doing so, I'll leave questions again. Thank you!

Comment: I used the source code you gave me,
I put both `MicrophoneReceiver.cs` and `MicrophoneTransmitter.cs` on a game object in Unity (so I thought I could send and receive voices).
Then I built one with Hololens App and one with a PC App(because I want to transfer voice between a server PC and hololens).
And I run the local server as shown in another link ,
Hololens and PC App,
but I could not hear anything.(Even though I checked 'Hear Self')
What am I wrong about?
I am a beginner in programming, so I don't know much about it. Sorry.

Comment: Another link about running the server is [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/External/HoloToolkit/Sharing/DocSource/MDFiles/GettingStarted.md#running-the-server)

Comment: Have you enabled the microphone on your Unity project?

Comment: There was little progress.
From this post[link](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit/issues/72), I found out that I did not add the prefab 'sharing'.
So I put it with server pc IP(port number is already selected as 20602) in the scene,
and then I added an empty object with two voice-chat scripts(MicrophoneReceiver, MicrophoneTransmitter) under the camera.
(When I attached them to the camera directly, I got a message saying that the audio listener and the audio source do not work at the same time.)

Comment: After running the server, I played a laptop app and Hololens app respectively, and I got a message 'connected to session list server'.
(But If I run '.exe' inside server folder, it is turned off as soon as the screen is displyed. So I run the server 'Launch Sharing Service' in Unity.
That's my little progress. However, I cannot still hear any sound. I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: However, I had a question. 
I'm trying to get voice streaming (from Hololens to PC)
Is it necessary to create Unity App?:
Can I get the voice only within a Unity app or by running it?
Is there another way to send voice streaming and access it?